Как удалить историю коммитов на github
случайно слил API ключ в файле и запушил на гитхаб, потом заметил и удалил. в историях коммита он теперь все равно виден. как убрать?

никак. меняйте ключ, пока не поздно.

Если это последний коммит в истории, то git reset --hard коммит на предыдущий коммит, а потом git push --force.
Если после него уже накопились полезные коммиты, то git rebase --interactive коммит на последний хороший коммит перед залитием ключа (или раньше). Откроется текстовый редактор, в котором можно закомментировать плохой коммит. После выхода из редактора он пропадет из истории. Затем тот же git push --force чтобы залить изменения.

Но согласен с комментом @aleksandr barakin, что ключ лучше поменять.

Сам GitHub рекомендует использовать следующие 2 программы для очистки истории коммитов:

BFG Repo-Cleaner
git-filter-repo

Когда у меня была такая проблема, мне помогла именно первая программа. У неё простая документация и она быстрее аналога в несколько раз.
Например, так вы можете полностью заменить текст вашего файла в истории коммитов:
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt

Затем пушим коммит:
git push --force

После проделанных операций рекомендую на всякий случай составить обращение (желательно на английском языке) в поддержку GitHub. Они достаточно спокойно реагируют на данные обращения и помогают "зачистить" остатки, если, например, произошло слияние через Pull Request.
